# Firefly references on Castle

Tags: character, reference, firefly, castle

I have begun watching [Castle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219024/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (in rerun) and have a chuckle every time there is a [Firefly](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_38) reference made.  [Nathan Fillion](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0277213/?ref_=tt_cl_t1) always gives a little smirk/wink.

**Season 4, episode 16 - Setup**: 
Martha asks Castle if he has heard about "Serenity" (a spa in the catskills)

**Season 2 episode 6 - Vampire Weekend**: 
Castle puts on his Halloween "costume", a space cowboy, the same he wore in Firefly ("like 5 years ago", as Alexis says - the entire dialog is hilarious).

What (if any) are some other episodes (season and number) with references to Firefly?

Comment: While I too enjoy both Firefly and Castle, this question may be off topic as it is a list type question. Nathan Fillion is a very good actor, with very believable characters.

Comment: Maybe, but I am not asking about favorite references, but what allusions exists, so is in the realm of content and theme.  Would it be better if explicitly ask for season and episode?

Comment: You are probably right! I know I have seen several references, including the two you list above. I know there is probably more. I, unfortunately, have only started watching them through syndication, so don't have any sort of order to what I have seen. Looking forward to seeing what else exists.

Comment: Think this question is fine, because it's a finite list. It's not like it's collecting things based on some assumption, story element or opinion.

Comment: @Mario It is not finite as Castle is still an ongoing series.

Comment: Maybe a better question would be what the director's/writer's take was with these references. I believe it is kind of _tongue in cheek humor_, but wouldn't hurt to know what their idea was behind this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFj8eFZx-TA
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7TIjFpq_-E

Comment: Thanks @MeatTrademark.  Ya know, I never even thought to check YouTube.  Make that an answer an I will accept ... although, I have a feeling that there are/will be more references :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a **bunch**.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFj8eFZx-TA)

*Yes*, it's a short answer, but this is probably what the OP was after. It's not complete but it's certainly fun. I did not transcribe the link because it's been around over two years and I don't anticipate it being gone anytime soon. If anything, I hope it's updated. *Also because **I haven't watched Castle** and do not care to research where every quote came from during its run thus far.*

"...didn't you wear that like, **five years ago**?" is by far my favorite, with the Chinese bit after it from "a TV show I used to love" being a close second.

[**This** clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7TIjFpq_-E) is *similar*, but has the Firefly instances to compare.

**EDIT:** Undeleted post to make answer per @WayneWeibel's request.

Comment: Link only answers are not recommended as links can die at any time.

Comment: I know. That's why I worded it the way I did and provided another link. Feel free to watch every episode of Castle to reference episodes, or to transcribe the entire video. I'm a Firefly fan but am not going to do THAT much work for an ever-changing answer. I just wanted this person to see this link to get some references they may have missed. As Castle is still ongoing a definitive answer is not yet possible.

Comment: That's what comments are for. If you dislike the nature of the question, try to improve it, downvote, or vote to close. When your provided link no longer exists, you answer becomes useless to all future visitors.

Comment: I agree, this should be a comment as it only provides links (and some text explaining why it only provides links).

Comment: If you read through the thread, and my edit, you'll see that this was all at the OP's request. That was my motivation for undeleting it. Given that, and that he accepted it, it does no harm to leave up. If need be, I'll check on it every now and then to make sure the links work, or to update them.

Comment: I *know* it's a shabby answer, but the links are still active as of today, bit over 3 years on. That's something, I guess. (as per prior post)

Comment: Link still up. Good to go! Still funny, too.